# Mule Esb run in background from linux command

Tags: linux, mule, esb

i can't figure out how to start a mule esb from command terminal in linux without keep calling the wrapper, which obliges me to mantain active the terminal.

I can actually use this simple command (from bin directory):

> ./mule

Anyways, if i need to pass a parameter, like this:

> ./mule -Denv=prod

it keeps starting in foreground mode.

How can I achieve a background start with parameters?

thanks!

Comment: Have you tried ```./mule start``` with parameters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just tried it: `./mule start` works in background with params (if needed). You can then stop it running `./mule stop`. HTH.

Comment: right, needed the "start" for the background as specified here: https://developer.mulesoft.com/docs/display/34X/Starting+and+Stopping+Mule+ESB

Answer (score 0):

Mule will be handled by the script which is placed at `MULE_HOME/bin/mule`. This script supports `start|stop|restart|status|dump|console`.

For production mode Mule should be configured as deamon as well - `systemctl` or `service`.